# Android Socket in same process or separate

Tags: android, android-service, android-parser

I am creating a android app that uses a TCP socket to connect to a server. It continuously receives xml strings from this socket and I need to parse it as it comes. Currently I've implemented the socket in a service in the same process of the application.

I get outofmemory exception sometimes. The xml strings I receive will be around 1-3mb.
My question is, will it be more efficient if a run my service in a separate process as my socket constantly needs to work? What is the best way to implement a socket in android which works the app life span?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should  definitely put your socket in a thread. If it's not the case you take the chance to freeze the entire application on network timeout for example.

There is several different way to make a thread in android. My favorite is to create a class which extends Thread.

have a look to the [painless threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) in android doc and the more general [Processes and Threading article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html)

Comment: My socket is in another thread in the service. But the thing is my socket is taking a bit of resources as I am parsing the response. So I considered another process to get another memory heap.

Comment: Also the class/tool you're using to parse XML can have much influence on memory usage, regarding if it's event-based (light) or tree-based (heavy, has to be loaded completely), how are you doing that?

Comment: @darma I am using the SaxParser.